# Prove the sum of a convergent and a divergent sequence is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

> **Question:**
>   Let ($a_n$)$_{n∈\mathbb N}$ and ($b_n$)$_{n∈\mathbb N}$ be sequences such that $\lim_{n→∞}$ $(a_n)$ = ∞ and $\lim_{n→∞}$$(b_n)$ = b ∈ $\mathbb R$.
>   Show that
>   $\lim_{n→∞}$($a_n$ + $b_n$) = ∞.

**My answer:**

Lets assume $\lim_{n→∞}$($a_n$ + $b_n$) = p ∈ $\mathbb R$.
We are told that $\lim_{n→∞}$$b_n$ = b ∈ $\mathbb R$.

$\Rightarrow \forall \epsilon_1 $ $\exists N_1\in\mathbb R$ :n>$N_1 \Rightarrow |b_n -b| < \epsilon_1$
and $\forall \epsilon_2 $ $\exists N_2\in\mathbb R$ :n>$N_2 \Rightarrow |a_n+b_n -p| < \epsilon_2$

Set: $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$ and $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

For n>N:

$|a_n-(p-b)|=|a_n+b_n-b_n-p+b|=|(a_n+b_n-p)-(b_n-b)|\leq |a_n+b_n-p|+|b_n-b|<\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n→∞} (a_n) = p-b\in\mathbb R$ which is a contradiction since $\infty \notin \mathbb R$
$\Rightarrow p\notin \mathbb R$.

Hence $\lim_{n→∞}(a_n+ b_n) = \infty$

I'm unsure if this answers the question, as I think I have only shown that $\lim_{n→∞}(a_n+ b_n) $ diverges - not specifically to $\infty$.

I feel like I need to use the definition of a sequence which diverges to infinity:

$\forall K\in\mathbb R^+$ $\exists N_K\in \mathbb N: n>N_K \Rightarrow a_n>K$

But I am unsure on how to implement this after several attempts of fiddling with the inequalities.

Comment: This is not home-work solving service. Please show your effort so far.

Comment: Sorry have not used this too much, accidentally uploaded the question before uploading answer. It took me a while to learn how to format the answer.

Comment: But $\lim (a_n+b_n) = p$ and $\lim (a_n + b_n) = \infty$ are not the only two options.  You could have $\lim(a_n+b_n) \ne \pm \infty$ and not converge at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lim a_n = \infty$ that means, by definition, that for any $M$ there is an $N_1$ so that if $n > N_1$ then $a_n > M$.

And $\lim b_n = b$ means, by definition that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N_2$ so that if $n > N_2$ then $|b_n - b| < \epsilon$.

So if $n > \max(N_2,N_1)$ we have $a_n > M$ and $b -\epsilon < b_n <b+ \epsilon$ so $a_n + b_n > b+M - \epsilon$.

That should tell us something if $\epsilon$ is small enough.....

========

For any $M$:

If we let $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and $N_2$ be the required value so $n > N_2$ means $|b_n -b| < \epsilon$.

And we can let $M' = M-b +1$ then we can find an $N_3$ be the required value value so that $n > N_3$ means $a_n >M' = M-b +1$

Then if $n > \max(N_2, N_3)$ then $b_n > b-\epsilon > b-1$ and $a_n > M' = M-b+1$ so $a_n + b_n > (M-b+1)+(b-1) = M$.

So $\lim (a_n + b_n) = \infty$.

Comment: Nice thats the way I was trying to do it. I got about halfway with this but didnt think to let $0<\epsilon<1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Remember:** to make a proof by contradiction, we typically suppose the opposite of what we want to conclude. When you arrive at your contradiction only having made one assumption, that one assumption *must* be false, if your derivation is correct.

For your specific problem, you seem to arrive at your contradiction when you conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\infty$ *and* $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=p-b<\infty$. This obsviously cannot be true. And thus your assumption must be false. (What is your assumption?)

So in the end it does not really matter where you end up - you can conclude that $1>2$, that is as much of a contradiction as your contradiction. And since nothing false can follow from something true, the assumption has to be false.

Comment: So my assumption that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=p\in\mathbb R$ is incorrect, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n) diverges $ ? So my proof does not answer the question as I need to show it diverges to +$\infty$?

Comment: I've had an idea. Since I have proven that it diverges I can then use $\forall K\in\mathbb R^+$ $\exists N_K\in\mathbb N:n>N_K$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_n>K$ to show that it specifically diverges to +$\infty$?

Comment: You could also try to use a contradiction again, because you really only have two options here, either the sequence diverges to $\infty$ or it diverges to $-\infty$. So if you manage to rule out $-\infty$, you're done. The fun thing when contradicting statements concerning *all* instances of something, is that you only need to show that it is wrong for *one* of the instances to get your contradiction.

Comment: $\lim (a_n + b_n) = p$ for some $p \in \mathbb R$ is false.  But that in no way means that $\lim (a_n+b_n)= \infty$.  Consider $v_n = n\pmod 3$ that is $\{v_n\} = 1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0$.  $\lim v_n \ne p; \lim v_n \ne =\pm \infty$.

Comment: the negation of $\lim(a_n+b_n)=\infty$ would be: the is a  value, $D$ for which there will be infinitely many $a_n+b_n < D$ (no matter how large $n$ is).  Now we can find and $N$ where $n>M$ means $b_n < b+\epsilon$ so if there are infinitely many $a_n+b_n < D$ there are infinitely many $a_n < D-b -\epsilon < D-b$. But that conradicts that $a_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm correct or dumb because this stuff can be confusing, but I don't see anything wrong with it. And I admit I'm stealing/borrowing the first part from fleablood's answer, but I believe I have an important divergence in methods half way through. And a slight change in notation to fleablood's for readability ($t$).

$\lim a_n = \infty$ means, $\quad \forall \ M_1\ \exists \ N_1: n > N_1 \implies a_n > M_1 \qquad (1)$

$\lim b_n = b$ means, $\quad \forall \ \epsilon >0\ \exists \ t \in \mathbb N: n > t \implies |b_n - b| < \epsilon \qquad (2)$

So if $n > \max(N_1, t)$ we have, as fleablood showed, that $a_n + b_n > b+M_1 - \epsilon \qquad (*)$

Now this is where I depart from fleablood's method. Let $M_2 \in \mathbb N$. I need to show $\exists\ N_2: n> N_2 \implies a_n + b_n > M_2$.

Choose $M_1 > M_2 + \epsilon - b.\ $ Then $\exists\ N_1: n>N_1 \implies a_n > M_1 > M_2 + \epsilon -b.\ $ Using this value of $N_1$, if $n> max(N_1, t),\ $ from $\ (*)\ $ we have $a_n + b_n > b+M_1 - \epsilon > M_2.$

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that, in fact I prefer this one more. Very nice!